# Entity Framework: Adding collection (list, HashSet, Dictionary) to User Object results in blank Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to work off of the pre-built Entity website that comes with MVC4, and I'm trying to change the user object to include extra fields.

If I have the following code in AccountModels.cs

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Test { get; set; }
}
```

(Note, I added List Test {get;set;})

And then I run the following in the Package Manager Console,

```
Add-Migration "List"
Update-Database
```

The resulting Migration class is this.

```
public partial class List : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

However, if I just add a scalar variable to the AccountModels.cs, then it shows up in the generated migration class no problem, like so:

```
public partial class singleString : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NameList", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "NameList");
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work when I try and add a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you expect Entity Framework to map `List<string>`. String isn't going to map to any database table. It's just a string. If you changed it to a class then it would create a migration for it.

Entity Framework treats `ICollection<T>` as a one-to-many relationship (unless there is a collection on the other end of the relationship). Since you are using a string, it doesn't see that as any sensible database mapping since it can't map string to a table. If you added a new class like the following:

```
[Table("UserAddress")]
public class UserAddress
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserAddressId{ get; set; }

    // foreign key to UserProfile
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    // navigation property to UserProfile
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Now if you were to change UserProfile to include addresses:

```
 public List<UserAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
```

EF will create a migration that adds a new table with a one to many relationship between UserProfile and UserAddress.